# How to make Google custom search API multiple calls by increasing startIndex (start) parameter to show more than 10 results at once in PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-custom-search, google-search-api

I have looked many questions similar to this one, but can't find the helpful answer.

As I know, it is not possible to receive more than 10 results from Google custom search API. However, I want to know how do I make multiple calls by increasing startIndex (start) parameter to show more result.

Below is my code to increase the `start` parameter statically.

```
$json_string_1 = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key='.$api_key.'&cx='.$cx.'&q='.$q.'&start=1';

$jsondata_1 = file_get_contents($json_string_1);
$obj_1 = json_decode($jsondata_1, true);
print_r($obj_1);


$json_string_2 = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key='.$api_key.'&cx='.$cx.'&q='.$q.'&start=11';

$jsondata_2 = file_get_contents($json_string_2);
$obj_2 = json_decode($jsondata_2, true);
print_r($obj_2);
```

How do I call `start` parameter dynamically as if I have `n` number of `startIndex` OR any way to call this API in a loop so `startIndex` will auto-increment by 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out how to loop API with multiple calls by increasing `start` and get the complete result at once.

```
$count = 200;

for($page=1; $page < $count; $page=$page+10) { 

    $json_string_1 = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key='.$api_key.'&cx='.$cx.'&q='.$q.'&start='.$page;

    $jsondata_1 = file_get_contents($json_string_1);
    $obj_1 = json_decode($jsondata_1, true);

    foreach ($obj_1["items"] as $data) {
        echo $data["title"]."<br>";
    }
}
```

In the above code, get the `$count` value from the query search results like,

```
$totalResults = $data["searchInformation"]["totalResults"];
$count = $totalResults/10; //per page number of counts are 10
```